Parameter Separator with Jenkins plugin
I'm starting to use the Parameter Separator plugin to separate the configuration parameters of a job that has many parameters.
The definition of the parameters is loaded from a configuration file. what is the syntax to separate parameters with a separator line?
I am trying this but the line is not showing
function()[
    {
      type: 'separator',
      name: 'myseparator', 
      sectionHeader: 'example separator',  
    }, 
    {
      type: 'choice',
      name: 'VERIFY_VERSION',
      value: '"SI\\nNO"',
      defaultValue: '"SI"',
      description: '¿Verificar las versiones?',      
    },
...

Thanks

Loading parameters definitions from a configuration file is not a self explanatory thing. And the code fragment doesn't look like groovy. How do you load parameters definitions? Is it a plugin? a groovy script?

Hi. Yes, I use Jenkins Configuration as Code plugin to define the configuration in a configuration file. I need to know if it is possible to configure the plugin in a parameter configuration file.
